# How can I escape an apostrophe to match data from a MySQL database in Node.js/Discord.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I know how escaping works in general, but in this case, I cannot get it to give me the desired results.

I have a table with a list of cards in it. At the top of the command, I have the query push each card name into an array as a "master list." Later on in the code, I have the users provide card names they would like to add to their deck. In order to check that they are using cards that exist, exactly as spelled, it takes each card name the user provides and tries to find it in the master list array.

However, when the user provides a card name with an apostrophe in it (i.e. `Drago's Fury`), it refuses to find the card name in the list.

I have tried replacing all occurrences of `'` with `\'` and `''` and several combinations of the two, multiple `\'`s and multiple `' '`s in various amounts. Nothing seems to let me match it. `Drago's Fury` in the table does contain the `'`s in the name as expected, because I was able to put it into the table by escaping it with `\'`.

Here's the code I have:

```js
con.query(`SELECT * FROM cardsmaster`, (error, rows, fields) => {
    let cardsList = []
    for (var i in rows) {
        cardsList.push(rows[i].name)
    }
});
```

Here is how `Drago's Fury` is listed in the MySQL table:
[image: MySQL Table]

This is what I'm using right now to try and escape it and make it find `Drago's Fury` when it is provided inside Discord from a user:

```js
cardsToAdd = cardsToAdd.content.replace(/'/gi, "\'");
```

This is how `cardsToAdd` displays `Drago's Fury` when it's logged after the replacement:

[image: Console]

But then I receive this error:

> `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Fury, Fierce Boost, Fierce Boost, Fiery Rage, Fire Boost, Fire Boost, Magma Bo' at line 1`

So, I tried:

```js
cardsToAdd = cardsToAdd.content.replace(/'/gi, "\\'");
```

I was thinking that the first `\` would escape the second `\` and the apostrophe, but that isn't exactly what I want. The incoming value is the same, except that it has double quotes instead of single, so I'm not certain if that is causing the problem or not...

This is the section that tries to take what the user gives and finds it in the master list:

```js
let usercardnamearray = cardsToAdd.split(", ")

let matchedcards = []
let unmatchedcards = []

for (let i = 0; i < usercardnamearray.length; i++) {

    console.log(usercardnamearray[i])

    let found = cardsList.indexOf(`${usercardnamearray[i]}`)
    console.log(found)

    if (found >= 0) {
        matchedcards.push(usercardnamearray[i])
    } else if (found == -1){
        unmatchedcards.push(usercardnamearray[i])
    }
}
```

How can I consistently match the provided name in the master list?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Have a look into using prepared statements. This will also solve your issue.

Comment: @frobinsonj So, are you suggesting I use ?'s as placeholders? I don't exactly see how that would help as what a user provides is being checked with a list first via indexOf, which is filtering out unacceptable inputs? I am probably just missing the point here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: By using placeholders (`?`), the input is automatically escaped for you. This will prevent injection and your current error, without you having to do anything else yourself.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I've used something similar before, in the form of this format. https://i.gyazo.com/5f78ea354de8213664e33f708cf7226e.png

Would that work the way you're suggesting? I ran it and it can't find any result now, but I think that is just a matter of me updating the code to work with the change.

Comment: Okay, I did that one the cardList variable at the top of the command, and it looks like when looking for the card in the list, it is finding it! Also changed it in the INSERT query later on, and it also worked flawlessly! Thanks so much! @JackRed If you want to post your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you and slothiful both!

Comment: You're right, except I think it was @frobinsonj instead. Sorry, my bad! slothiful did help explain it as well, but I think they brought up the suggestion first. For some reason, it wouldn't like me tag both of them in that comment. It says "only one additional @ user can be notified".

Comment: Placeholders are a little different than prepared statements. If I understand the back-end workings of placeholders, they escape by translating the string to the MySQL protocol. However, this is done server-side rather than client-side.

Comment: @slothiful So, is what I did (albeit, I changed it to actually work by putting the inserts in brackets) still help prevent SQL injection? I mean, it fixed the primary problem I was having, but for security issues, I should make sure it works.

Comment: Placeholders do indeed prevent SQL injection. The [`node-mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) driver uses `mysql.escape()` for them automatically. That's why your apostrophe doesn't trigger the same error - it's being read literally rather than as part of the statement.

Comment: @slothiful Makes sense to me. I don't really know which of you deserves the correct answer reward more in this regard. I did upvote both of the comments I found helpful regardless. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, by using placeholders (`?`), the input is automatically escaped for you; the [`node-mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) driver uses `mysql.escape()` for them on its own. This will prevent injection and your current error, without you having to do anything else yourself. Your apostrophe won't trigger the same error since it's being read literally rather than as part of the statement.

Example usage:

```js
const name = "Drago's Fury";

con.query("SELECT * FROM cardmaster WHERE name = ?", [name], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  console.log(rows);
})
```